# Blender becomes very slow with large amount of objects sharing mesh data

Tags: python, performance, data-blocks

In my script I am importing a large amount of objects (+2500) but sharing the mesh data from one single primitive. While this has taken care of importing speed, it completely slows blender down. However when I import as individual primitives blender is very responsive even with + 2500 objects.

Why does blender slow down (frame rate, buttons, etc) when sharing mesh data blocks and is there anyway to aliviate this?

Code:

```
def create_mesh(name, radius, locat):
    #print (fList)

    # Create mesh and object
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Sphere')
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes['Primary']
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new('Shpere', mesh)
    #obj.show_name = True
    obj.scale = (radius, radius, radius)
    obj.location = locat 

    # Link object to scene and make active
    scn = bpy.context.scene
    scn.objects.link(obj)
    #scn.objects.active = obj
    #obj.select = True


    # Update mesh with new data
    mesh.update() 

    return obj
```

Comment: Is it necessary to update the mesh before returning the newly created object?

Comment: everything that I have read says that it should be updated, so I have.

Comment: I was thinking it should be obj.update() and not mesh.update()..

Comment: I'm not sure what you would update in the obj. AFAIK mesh.update() is to update the mesh to display correctly after working with it.

Comment: Actually.. there is no method called update() on objects.. I stand corrected.. I am taking your code and doing some tests.. will post my observations in sometime.. Cheers.

Comment: I posted an answer (community wiki version) after doing some tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to share some stats that I gathered after doing some tests. I think what you are facing could be viewport performance issues and nothing really about Python. Those issues can be improved by following some optimizations (which are demonstrated below)

**One Suzanne mesh linked to 7497 Objects**

In the viewport, with all the objects selected, I invoked the `Redraw Timer` operator (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and chose `Draw Region + Swap` option for the following cases

> With `Outline Selected` checked on (under Display Panel of Properties Panel <kbd>N</kbd>)

```
Warning: 10 x Draw Region and Swap: 9437.80 ms,  average: 943.7801
```

> With `Outline Selected` checked off

```
Warning: 10 x Draw Region and Swap: 7264.04 ms,  average: 726.4040
```

> With `Outline Selected` checked off and VBOs Checked On (Sunder System Tab of User Preferences Editor <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)

```
Warning: 10 x Draw Region and Swap: 1672.37 ms,  average: 167.2374
```

**All 7497 Objects having their own copies of Suzanne Mesh**

and following similar test cases as above, I got the following results

```
Warning: 10 x Draw Region and Swap: 7910.51 ms,  average: 791.0507

Warning: 10 x Draw Region and Swap: 5558.50 ms,  average: 555.8497

Warning: 10 x Draw Region and Swap: 1815.82 ms,  average: 181.5816
```

I hope this helps in what you are doing.

[image: Lots of Linked Meshes Test]

Note: The *VBOs* checkbox below the *Backface Culling* was customized by me (by editing the python user interface files). VBOs setting is actually present in the User Preferences Editor.

Comment: These have all helped. Also, instead of using uv_spheres I have switched to nurbs spheres and that has helped a lot. And I didn't know about the Redraw Timer. Thanks for that, this will be extremely useful optimizing the importer. When I get this working well, I'll post what I did.

Comment: 2500 nurbs spheres with a material slot but no material: Draw Region + Swap - Warning: 10 x Draw Region and Swap: 2282.79 ms,  average: 228.2791
 and this is working far better than it was before. I starting to think that this might be my system although I have 16gb ram on a Imac27 I5 and ATI 512mb.

Comment: Excellent :) Looking forward to your script.

Comment: @satishgoda why did you make this wiki? It doesn't need to be. I changed it back.

Comment: @iKlsR Was not sure if this was an answer that directly answers the question.. That is why. Thank you for taking the appropriate action. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

You're sharing one object data (`Primary`) among +2500 objects, but with this line:

```
bpy.data.meshes.new('Sphere')
```

... you're also creating +2500 orphan mesh data. It's easy to add several MBs to Blender's memory usage (verifiable through System Monitor), just running that bit of code:

```
import bpy

for i in range(1, 2500):
    bpy.data.meshes.new('Sphere')
```

The orphaned obdatas won't be reclaimed until loading new scene or quitting (to see them, select a mesh object, click the dropdown button to the left of the obdata's name in **Properties** area's **Object Data** tab). For scenes large enough, in systems with low RAM, this could slow down the whole system.

Comment: Will the garbage collector not reclaim the memory since  it was orphaned?

Comment: probably not until the file is saved/reopened? Since I believe we are talking about BPY objects, not plain python objects.

Comment: Ahh.. I see what you mean. Looks like Adhi updated his answer as well. Cool. Thanks.

Comment: However, that doesn't explain why when I import and create a separate "primitive" for each line, blender doesn't have those memory issues. BTW, I tried saving and reopening the file and that doesn't help at all.

Comment: I have updated the code to: mesh = bpy.data.meshes('Primary') however this doesn't do anything to help the issue

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @satishgoda also reminded me of a suggestion by PsyFi or Sabiantian_k.

Closing the outliner can speed up the viewport performance as the data view is is constantly being polled for updates. As the number of objects being checked for updates increase, it impacts performance.

Comment: Thats interesting. It doesn't make a huge difference but it does help and you can tell it works

Comment: Yeah it was just a random funny point they brought up about their time during the TOS project. They were thinking about making it more dynamic in what it actually polled but not sure if it was actually submitted as a feature improvement. It might already be that way.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need to factor `scn.objects.link(obj)` out of your function and place it in a separate loop, so that creation and linkage of objects to the scene are separated between different loops. When you use `scn.objects.link(obj)` whithin the same iteration where you create object, blender updates all the scene every iteration. See answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7360/3153 with comments to it. Your code may transform to something like this:

```
def create_mesh(name, radius, locat):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes['Primary']
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    obj.scale(radius, radius, radius)
    obj.location = locat 
    return obj

obs = []
for name, radius, locat in params2500:
    o = create_mesh(name, radius, locat)
    obs.append(o)

sc = bpy.context.scene
for o in obs:
    sc.objects.link(o)
```