# I cant run a particle related script. It says "bpy_struct : item.attr = val : sequences of dimensions 0 should contain 4 items, not 3" in line 28

Tags: materials

So I was trying use this script from reddit https://github.com/JaredTS486/Blender_Particles/blob/master/particles.py
Then I encountered this problem where it says

```
bpy_struct : item.attr = val : 
 sequences of dimensions 0 should contain 4 items, not 3
```

Here my code for material is

```
def makeMaterial(name, diffuse, specular, alpha):
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name)
    mat.diffuse_color = diffuse
    mat.diffuse_shader = 'LAMBERT' 
    mat.diffuse_intensity = 1.0 
    mat.specular_color = specular
    mat.specular_shader = 'COOKTORR'
    mat.specular_intensity = 0.5
    mat.alpha = alpha
    mat.ambient = 1
    return mat

red = makeMaterial('Red',      (1,0,0), (1  ,1  ,1), 1)
yellow = makeMaterial('Yellow',(1,1,0), (1  ,1  ,1), 1)
blue = makeMaterial('Blue',    (0,0,1), (1  ,1  ,1), 1)
green = makeMaterial('Green',  (0,1,0), (0.5,0.5,0), 0.5)
white = makeMaterial('White',  (1,1,1), (0.5,0.5,0), 0.5)
black = makeMaterial('Black',  (0,0,0), (0.5,0.5,0), 0.5)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Re-jig the script for RGBA**

The script was written in 2013 a time when the now defunct blender internal render material colors did not include the alpha channel, as demonstrated by a simple test in python console

```
>>> D.materials['Material'].diffuse_color[:]
(0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 1.0)
```

This is what the error is telling you. In case above for `diffuse_material` property of material has 4 elements not 3.

Edit, and test in python console to suit current status.

Somewhat related [Pixel to voxel in Blender 2.92](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219522/pixel-to-voxel-in-blender-2-92)

Note. Will run into more errors, once again testing in the python console using <kbd>TAB</kbd> to auto complete, will show that the `specular_shader` option is also a thing of the past.

```
>>> D.materials['Material'].specular_
                                     color
                                     intensity
```

(Alternatively use a pre 2.8 version of blender)