# How can I use the blender python API to make a scatter plot animation of millions of objects?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, particles, cache

I have produced some data, that I would like to visualize with some eye candy. The data is contained in a 3D numpy array `a`.  `a[t,j,k]` would be the k-th component of the position of the j-th object at time t. Though I am flexible changing that if need be.

I thought of two ways of implementing this. One is a script that creates instances of a mesh and writes keyframes for them but that implementation uses python for loops and since I want an animation for about one minute this will take too long. Using multiprocessing or just multi threading wasn't working as soon as I touched anything from bpy.
Perhaps using a particle system will be more suitable for this task. Here I also an instance object. I found some code from the post
[How can I create many objects quickly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39721/how-can-i-create-many-objects-quickly)
but the API seemed to change over time, so it doesn't quite work. I rewrote what I could find only random initialization is possible.

```
def create_many_copies(target_obj, count):
    # Create a particle system container
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    cube = bpy.context.object

    # Create a particle system within the container
    bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
    particle_sys = cube.particle_systems[0].settings

    # Set parameters so all particles show up at once
    particle_sys.frame_start = -1
    particle_sys.frame_end = 1

    particle_sys.count = count

    particle_sys.emit_from = 'VOLUME'

    # No random rotations
    particle_sys.use_rotations = True
    particle_sys.rotation_mode = 'NONE'

    # No physics
    particle_sys.physics_type = 'NO'

    # Use instance object for particle
    particle_sys.render_type = 'OBJECT'
    particle_sys.instance_object = target_obj
    particle_sys.particle_size = 1.0
    particle_sys.use_rotation_instance = True
    particle_sys.use_scale_instance = True

    # Make sure we're at the correct frame
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1) 

    # Looping over new position vectors
    # This results in an error telling me I am supposed to give it an
    # array of length 0, but gave array with length 30. Here 30 = len(locs).

    locs = np.arange(count * 3)
    cube.particle_systems[0].particles.foreach_set('location', locs)


bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add()
target = bpy.context.object 
create_many_copies(target, 10)
```

I don't really mind random initialization nor do I need the locations of the particles, as long as I can animate the locations using keyframes anyway. I would really appreciate a solution to keyframing the particles using the .foreach_set() method. If all this is too cumbersome and not 'the right way', then please tell me.

If it is possible to just forgo running a script in blender at all, I am all for it. Can I perhaps use python to 'bake' data and use it as external cache for a particle system inside blender? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems and ended up creating a python-only addon called [blender-plots](https://github.com/Linusnie/blender-plots) which provides animated scatterplots. I've managed to avoid looping so far using these approaches:

- Creating many copies of the same object: create a mesh with vertices at each point you want an object and use an `Instance on Points` node to set the appearance
- Creating mesh: use `mesh.from_pydata(vertices, [], [])`
- Updating vertices on existing mesh: use `mesh.vertices.foreach_set("co", vertices.reshape(-1))` (vertices = Nx3 numpy array)
- Animating vertices: See below

To create an animation, first load the vertices for all timestamps as a single mesh, then add a `frame_index` attribute to each vertex (frame_index_per_vertex = length-N numpy array):

```
mesh.attributes.new(name="frame_index", type="FLOAT", domain="POINT")
mesh.attributes[attribute_name].data.foreach_set("value", frame_index_per_vertex)
```

Then add a geometry node modifier set up to only show the vertices where `frame_index` matches the current frame:
[image]
The first `Value` field in the Compare node is keyframed to interpolate between 1 and n_frames. If you use the addon all this is set up automatically :)

It would also be possible to keyframe the individual vertex positions directly to get proper interpolation (with the option above objects will make sharp jumps between frames), see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237145/how-can-i-add-many-keyframes-for-an-object-without-a-loop). However afaik it would require looping over every vertex with the current API.