# How do I generate random cylinders, with random height on a predefined area?

Tags: modeling, python, scripting

I am using the following python script to generate an amount of random cylinders that do not overlap with each other:

```
     import bpy
 from random import random
 from mathutils import Vector

 cylinderRadius    = 1
 maxIterations = 500 # Max iterations to prevent while loop from running 
 forever

# min and max values for each axis for the random numbers
ranges = {
   'x' : { 'min' : 7, 'max' : 10 },
   'y' : { 'min' : 7, 'max' : 10 },
   'z' : { 'min' : 0, 'max' : 0}
  }

# Generates a random number within the axis minmax range
randLocInRange = lambda axis: ranges[axis]['min'] + random() * ( 
ranges[axis]['max'] - ranges[axis]['min'] )

size  = 50 # Number of cylinders
cylinders = []  # Cylinders coordinates list

loopIterations = 0
while len( cylinders ) < size and loopIterations < maxIterations:
   loopIterations += 1

# Generate a random 3D coordinate
loc = Vector([ randLocInRange( axis ) for axis in ranges.keys() ])

if len( cylinders ) > 0:
    # Search for overlapping points (within the cylinder radius radius)
    overlappingPoints = [ p for p in cylinders if ( p - loc ).length < cylinderRadius * 2 ]

    # if any found, skip this location
    if overlappingPoints: continue

# Add coordinate to cylinder list
cylinders.append( loc )

# Add the first cylinder (others will be duplicated from it)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add( radius = cylinderRadius, location = 
cylinders[0] )
cylinder = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cylinder']

# Add all other cylinders
for c in cylinders[1:]:
    dupliCylinder = cylinder.copy()
    dupliCylinder.location = c
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link( dupliCylinder )
```

However, I do not get the 50 cylinders I am asking for when compiling. Does anyone have an idea on how to actually avoid setting a number of cylinders to be generated, but to fill in a pre-defined area (e.g. a square) with randomly placed cylinders, that do not overlap with each other, on it ? [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Kind of a 2d version of this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42232/15543

Comment: Do you want it in a triangle form as in your image or is it ok if it was in square form with a small gap in the middle. If so, try doing a loop for the y axis which has a loop for the x axis that adds 2 times the radius to that axis. To get 50 you would input 5 and 10 on the x and y values, giving you 5x10=50. Just giving a simpler approach...

Answer (score 3):

[image]
*Test run, settings as posted Placed 66 of 68*

**[Algorithm for random distribution of circles in a square](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89643/algorithm-for-random-distribution-of-circles-in-a-square)**

> This simple script to place a number of `num_circles` circles with
>   radius `radius` in a refined rectangle (aligned to global axes) speficied
>   by `xmin, xmax, ymin` and `ymax` by trying random locations until it not
>   colliding with an existing circle. This is certainly not the most
>   efficient way of doing it, but it should be fine for smaller problems
>   and if the relative area covered is not too high.

Test code after making a couple of edits to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89658/15543 to make it add cylinders of random height to a rectangle.

```
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from mathutils.noise import random, seed_set
import bpy

# Specify parameters
seed = 0
xmin = -10
xmax = 10
ymin = -10
ymax = 10
radius = 1
num_circles = 68
max_tries = 10000
max_height = 4
# Init
seed_set(seed)
sx = xmax - xmin - 2 * radius
sy = ymax - ymin - 2 * radius
xminm = xmin + radius
yminm = ymin + radius
existing_locations = []
sce = bpy.context.scene
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
    location=(0, 0, 0),
    depth=1,
    radius=radius)
ref_circle = bpy.context.object
ref_circle.data.transform(Matrix.Translation((0, 0, 0.5)))

# Loop
for i in range(num_circles):
    j = 0
    searchOn = True
    while searchOn:
        if j > max_tries: 
            print("Placed", i, "of", num_circles)
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            ref_circle.select_set(True)
            bpy.ops.object.delete()
            raise ValueError('Found no more room for another circle')
            break
        j += 1
        new_location = (xminm + random() * sx,
                        yminm + random() * sy,
                        0)
        for existing_location in existing_locations:
            if (Vector(existing_location) - Vector(new_location)).length < 2 * radius:
                break
        else:
            new_circle = ref_circle.copy()
            new_circle.dimensions.z = max_height * random()
            new_circle.location = new_location
            sce.collection.objects.link(new_circle)
            existing_locations.append(new_location)
            searchOn = False

ref_circle.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.delete()
context.view_layer.update()
```

Comment: Hi batFINGER, Thank you for this script of random generation of meshes. I have some questions about my script, can I send with a private message regarding the distribution of random cylinders and cubes.