# How to colour entire object based on its height

Tags: objects, color, height-map

I have a bunch eg 5,000 extruded objects (think columns) each of different height. All off these exist as a single object, ie they are grouped together rather than individual layer objects. I want to apply a colour ramp so that each of the individual columns are coloured based on their height value, rather than the entire group.

This doesn't mean that the colour ramp is applied against the z axis resulting in the object having a colour fade as is gets taller, but more like the entire coumn is coloured based on its maximum height, and therefore corresponding colour on the colour ramp.

The columns are "hex bins" of a 2km geographic area. Their individual height represents the urban density. See image attached.

Hope that makes sense. If you are able to post the script / specific setup for this then I would be grateful - I'm very, very new to Blender so please bear with me![image]

Comment: I can't see any way of elegantly doing that, shader nodes don't have access to object size information, as far as I can tell. Animation nodes might be able to do it, though I've never tried it myself

Comment: Could be done via vertex colour similarly to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136926/15543 as long as each object has a unique mesh, or is one single joined mesh.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your responses, @batFinger I don't think this would solve it as the colour assignment is random and for the entire object, rather than driven by the z value (max height). Essentially I want to colour the object based on this value. Thanks so much for your comments though!

Comment: I understand the question, and can easily modify script to use z values to set colour instead of random, sheesh.  Gives this result http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=45a44b304ba3ea3ee6f198645a1383b7 using blue - green - red colour ramp, similar to weight paint on a random set of cylinders via  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135808/how-do-i-generate-random-cylinders-with-random-height-on-a-predefined-area/135811#135811 The main issue is they are not animatable, ie once set remain at that value.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to achieve!! Thank you! Since I'm a complete noob, have you got an example of the modified script you used please? Would be very grateful. Thanks @Batfinger

Comment: Hi, is there any way to see an example of your setup to achieve this, eg. the script. Where / how do i run this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Achieving this with material nodes

I thought Generated and Object texture spaces differ and that can be used for this. Thanks to Robin Betts for figuring out the correct math.

Object's texture space goes from 0 to one in every direction on every axis from the origin of the object to the end of its bounding box in that axis, however Generated texture space matches the scale of global world space. If the origins of all objects are at their bottoms, their heights can be calculated by dividing the Z value of the object's texture space by the Z value of Generated texture space. The values can then be compressed to the desired range by dividing them by the height of the highest object. A Color Ramp node then can be used to remap the height values to colors:

[image]

Comment: Very good idea! Got a feeling  it could be done with a simple division, so long as the origin of the object is at Z=0..or the shader-tree compensates via object info.  A shading point's (Object-space Z)/(Generated Space Z) should = h? Since Object Space Z goes linearly from 0-h, and Generated Space Z goes linearly from 0-1.

Comment: Yes, it [can](https://imgur.com/nnlPTXp).. but I don't want to step on your answer.. I wouldn't have thought of it, myself

Comment: Surely a 'so simple' but very nice discovery. Only constraint: origin point have to be at the bottom of the mesh (if not, linearity is broken) and (0,0) gives 0 (using obj.z/gen.z, so left part of the colorramp). Any idea to get rid of that? (@RobinBetts)

Comment: @RobinBetts, thank you! It seems so obvious now that you pointed it out. I'll update the answer when I have a few spare minutes.

Comment: @lemon ... you're right.. perhaps we can put a shift in to avoid 0/0

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant, THANK YOU! A very innovative solution! I've tried this on individual, single objects (eg one pillar), but the object I have contains approx 5,000 individual pillars all of varying heights, if that makes sense? To get this effect applied to all objects individually, I will need to split these into individual, separate entities which makes this very difficult and long to do. Is there any way to apply this effect to a single object that's consists of eg 5k features \ pillars? Eg. Apply this to a group? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I have a bunch of extruded objects..." ... OK... I'll give this a go, but then, please edit your question and provide all the context. What are you doing? What is this for? How do the pillars look(share a screenshot maybe?)? What are you planning to do with them - animate, render as a still, etc.?

Comment: Hi Martin Z, apologies for this and for this question slightly changing from the original, I have updated it to reflect what I am trying to achieve. As I learn more about blender, more detail / terminology etc becomes clear. Thanks for anything you can help with

Comment: I don't think I will figure this one out after all... :/