# How do I create a new object using Python in Blender 2.80?

Tags: python, experimental-features

As part of an existing add-on, I'm trying to create an object and add it to the scene using Python. I followed a Blender Cookbook tutorial found here: [Three ways to create objects](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects). I use the following code to do so:

```
emptyMesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('emptyMesh')
theObj = bpy.data.objects.new("object_name", emptyMesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(theObj)
```

But I get the following error when I try to link `theObj` to the scene objects:

```
AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'
```

This works just fine in Blender 2.76-2.79, but doesn't work in the 2.80 test build I downloaded. Was there a change to the Python API? Or is this maybe a bug in the test build?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an incomplete development version

Comment: @Amir I really don't think it's necessary to change "Python in Blender" to  "Blender's Python API". Either it's a general Python question in which case it's off-topic or it will be using Blender's API.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In 2.8 Blender API, this is still not documented yet. After dir() inspection I've found a temporary solution, where you can replace the scene with the collection, as below:

```
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(theObj)
```

Comment: @justi What is `dir()` inspection?

Comment: @batFINGER yes, you are right - the suggested change is bpy.context.scene_collection.objects.link() but it doesn't work now. Why? Because it causes the AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'scene_collection'

Comment: @Justin I did the dir() command on the bpy.context object: dir(bpy.context) and got attributes

Comment: Yes I realize that, hence the suggestion of `context.scene.collection` and the query as to whether `context.scene.collection` and `context.collection` will necessarily be the same.