# How do I append an object from a python script in Blender2.8?

Tags: objects, append

I'd like to Append an object using a python script, and do it in Blender2.8.   I have found some code snippets to do this on 2.7x but having trouble on 2.8.

Below is what I tried.  I get this error on the last line:  AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'

Thanks for any suggestions or code snippet.  I am beginner level on Python, and intermediate level on Blender.

Matt

---

```
# current scene
scn = bpy.context.scene

# path to the blend
filepath = "//2019_template_01.blend"

# name of object(s) to append or link
obj_name = "Chassis"

# append, set to true to keep the link to the original file
link = False

# link all objects starting with 'Chassis'
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_from, data_to):

    data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects if name.startswith(obj_name)]

#link object to current scene
for obj in data_to.objects:

    if obj is not None:
       scn.objects.link(obj)
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95408/how-do-i-create-a-new-object-using-python-in-blender-2-80

Answer (score 3):

had the same problem! Here is the solution that worked for me:

change the last code snippet to following:

```
#link object to current scene
for obj in data_to.objects:

   if obj is not None:
      bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

you can also add collections and their content from other blendfiles with data_to.collections:

```
for col in data_to.collections:
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(col)
```