# 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I'm using Blender 2.8+ and I found a web page containing a nice [python script to generate a labyrinth](https://www.local-guru.net/blog/2012/5/21/blender-labyrinth-generator). I copied the script in Blenders text editor and an error occurred at *line 88*:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.link (object)
```

> AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'
>   Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Unfortunately, I have no idea what a `'bpy_prop_collection'` is and I don't know where to start fixing this issue. What I need to do in order to make the script work for Blender 2.8x?

Comment: Need waaay more information. "The error" is not a basis for debugging. At least paste error output and tell us what version you're using.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95408/how-do-i-create-a-new-object-using-python-in-blender-2-80  Found via  googling "`"site:blender.stackexchange.com bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'`"   For scripts like above, recommend adding  a comment to the blog re the error, or now by adding a link to upgraded to 2.8x code supplied by @brockmann

Answer (score 17):

*If you are interested*: As of Blender 2.8x `SceneObjects.link(object)` is gone due to the new [collection system](https://code.blender.org/2018/05/collections-and-groups/). You can use [`CollectionObjects.link(my_object)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionObjects.html?highlight=objects%20link#bpy.types.CollectionObjects.link) instead so you just need to replace a single line to "update the script" for Blender 2.8x:

```
- bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)
+ bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)
```

[Blender 2.80: Python API Changes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API)

---

#### [blender labyrinth generator 2.8x](https://www.local-guru.net/blog/2012/5/21/blender-labyrinth-generator):

```
from random import shuffle 
from array import * 
import bpy

N=1
S=2
E=4
W=8

odir = {}
odir[N] = S
odir[S] = N
odir[W] = E
odir[E] = W

WIDTH=40
HEIGHT=40

coords = []
faces = []

d = [[0 for col in range(WIDTH)] for row in range(HEIGHT)]

for i in range(0,WIDTH):
    for j in range(0, HEIGHT):
        d[i][j] = 0

def carve( x, y ):
    dirs = [N,S,W,E]
    shuffle(dirs)

    for i in dirs:
        print(i)
        nx = x
        if i == E:
            nx =  nx + 1
        if i == W:
            nx = nx - 1
        ny = y
        if i == S:
            ny = ny +1
        if i == N:
            ny = ny - 1
        if nx >= 0 and nx < WIDTH and ny >=0 and ny < HEIGHT and d[nx][ny] == 0:
                d[x][y] = d[x][y] | i
                d[nx][ny] = d[nx][ny]  | odir[i]
                carve(nx, ny)

carve(0,0)

idx=0
step = 0.1

for x in range(0,WIDTH):
    for y in range( 0, HEIGHT ):
        if ( d[x][y] & N ) == 0:
            coords.append((x * step , y * step, 0 ))
            coords.append(((x+1) * step, y * step, 0 ))
            coords.append(((x+1) * step, y * step, step ))
            coords.append((x * step, y * step, step ))
            faces.append(( idx, idx+1, idx+2, idx+3))
            idx+=4
        if ( d[x][y] & S ) == 0:
            coords.append((x * step , (y+1) * step, 0 ))
            coords.append(((x+1) * step, (y+1) * step, 0 ))
            coords.append(((x+1) * step, (y+1) * step, step ))
            coords.append((x * step, (y+1) * step, step ))
            faces.append(( idx, idx+1, idx+2, idx+3))
            idx+=4
        if ( d[x][y] & E ) == 0:
            coords.append(((x+1) * step, y * step, 0 ))
            coords.append(((x+1) * step, (y+1) * step, 0 ))
            coords.append(((x+1) * step, (y+1) * step, step ))
            coords.append(((x+1) * step, y * step, step ))
            faces.append(( idx, idx+1, idx+2, idx+3))
            idx+=4
        if ( d[x][y] & W ) == 0:
            coords.append((x * step, y * step, 0 ))
            coords.append((x * step, (y+1) * step, 0 ))
            coords.append((x * step, (y+1) * step, step ))
            coords.append((x * step, y * step, step ))
            faces.append(( idx, idx+1, idx+2, idx+3))
            idx+=4

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="MyMesh")

object = bpy.data.objects.new( 'MESH', mesh )
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link( object )

mesh.from_pydata( coords, [], faces )
mesh.update( calc_edges=True )
```