# Merging / stamping faces from another model

Tags: modeling, sculpting, faces

Sorry if i'm not at the good place or if my question has been already answered ( didn't find )

I wondering if there any function in blender that can help me to change a ( human ) face from another.
As you can see in my screen,
I want to change the right model face to the left model face.

What is the best way to reach this result ? I mean, after resizing, orienting ...

Is there any solution like the " stamp " tool in photoshop or I have to erase my right face, replace the left one and then merge ?

Thanks a lot ! [image: left to right]

Comment: There is no stamp that can use a mesh as a stamp But the *Shrinkwrap* modifier can project a mesh on the surface of another mesh. I would use a low-poly (4k-5k vertices) [base mesh of a human head](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-realistic-model-of-female-head-anna-1781059) and sculpt it with the *Elastic Deformation* and *Grab* brushes. The *Shrinkwrap* modifier with help you to get it into the final shape. Finer details can be baked into a normal map. Example: https://youtu.be/LSdKpYtNy_U?t=671

Comment: Maybe this helps. There are two free add-ons that can transfer shapekeys between different meshes. This one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119836/scripting-transferring-shape-keys-between-different-meshes/119867 (github: https://github.com/fblah/ShapeKeyTransferBlender) and this one https://mmemoli.gumroad.com/l/tOKEh (video https://youtu.be/CvMeK_IIw-Y)