# Update screen using python scripts

Tags: scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm working on a new iterative algorithm for generating geometries. I'm trying to update the screen for each iteration on the screen to monitor the results (real-time); blender doesn't respond during the calculations.

Note: I tried this command but didn't work:
bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW', iterations=1,time_limit=0)

Comment: Suggest also looking  at using a modal (see modal timer op template) and running each iteration in `modal` Not sure re the `wm.redraw_timer` op in particular,  running a lot of operators can slow down blender over time. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators  btw select code and hit ctrl-K or hit {} code button for code markdown.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right command (Problem Solved):
bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)