# Row Summing When Moving an Object

Tags: python, scripting, csv

I am trying to move an object using coordinates from a CSV file. The file is written by one python script and then read by a script in blender. Below is the script written to read the file in blender and move the object.

```
import csv
import bpy


shufflecsv_path = '/Users/Josh/Documents/shuffle.csv'

with open(shufflecsv_path) as file:
    shufflecsv = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",", quoting = 
    csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    for row in shufflecsv:

        bpy.data.objects['Object'].select = True
        bpy.data.objects['Plane'].select = False
        # row is a list with strings elements so must be converted in float

        x, y, z = -float(row[0]), -float(row[1]), -float(row[2])
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(x, y, z))
        print(x, y, z)
```

Below is the output of blender when I run the script.

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.15565, 13.5708, -1.47311), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.18565, 14.1581, -1.47311), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.15565, 14.1581, -1.47311), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.15565, 13.5708, -1.47311), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.18565, 14.1581, -1.47311), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
```

You can see that the output window shows the location of the object should be each of the coordinates, but the object is not at the expected final point.

I have found that when I run the script, the object is moved to a final point that turns out to be the sum of the first three x, y, and z coordinates of the csv file. Any insight, help, or code snippets to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the csv file has n lines and each rows x, y, z is (1, 1, 1)  would expect the object `bpy.data.objects['Object']` to be moved globally by  (n, n, n) from its original global location.  Is this not the case?

Comment: can you post the csv, or a portion of it?