# How to put similar named objects into collection in python?

Tags: python, objects, collections

I wrote a script that can detect similar objects based on the selected objects but can't put them in a collection named after selected objects.

**It's not working**.

```
import bpy 

selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

for selected_object in selected_objects:
    name = selected_object.name
    collections = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collections)
    bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern=f"*{name}*")
    objs = bpy.context.selected_objects
    coll = bpy.data.collections[name]

    for obj in objs:
        cols = obj.users_collection
        coll.objects.link(obj)
        for col in cols:
        col.objects.unlink(obj)
```

I want from:

[image]

To:

[image]

Comment: @RobinBetts: That's what he wrote ;) "I want to make a python script" -> i assume he wants to do this more than 100x and automated - so a python script makes sense.

Comment: @Chris Quite right. Deleted.

Answer (score 6):

I would do the same in python that I could do in the UI, which is to use [Select Pattern](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/scene_layout/object/selecting.html#bpy-ops-object-select-pattern), and then move these selected items to a Collection.

In python:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all( action='DESELECT' ) # Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Sphere*")

# if collection Sphere does not yet exist:
bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection( collection_index=0, is_new=True, new_collection_name='Sphere' ) # new collection
# else if collection Sphere does exist:
bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection( collection_index=2 ) # need collection index
```

Comment: Somewhat related, joining instead of adding to collection.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166446/15543

Comment: i wish the select pattern would be there in the open file menu.... :(

Comment: @Chris, if you mean Append or Link or File Open.... someone recently pointed out to me, it exists in a rather crude way in Append or Link.  To the right of the File View, Directory Path, is a search text box labeled in the helptext as search filter.  I think it's inferior but usable.   screencap for Append, filename, Objects at https://www.dropbox.com/s/pimmjg9yy7fda5p/blenderNameFilter.png

Answer (score 3):

Here is another script where Collection names are used, with link and unlink:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all( action='DESELECT' ) # Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Sphere*")
objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

sphColl = bpy.data.collections['Spheres']

for obj in objs:
    print(obj)
    cols = obj.users_collection # ptr to current collection
    sphColl.objects.link(obj) # link into 'Spheres' collection
    print(cols)
    for col in cols:
        col.objects.unlink( obj ) # unline from original collection
```

Answer (score 3):

**Object to collection by name.**

Similarly to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166446/15543 can do this with API methods.

- Sort all objects in scene by name (could change this to selected
  objects if desired)
- Get the name up to the ".", eg for "Cube.022" this is "Cube", and all objects that start with this name
- Move to collection of same name. Make a new collection and link to scene collection if need be.  *This will ensure can run this again and again and again without moving "Cube" to collection named "Cube.001" then "Cube.002" etc*
- Repeat until all objects moved.
- Optionally remove any collections left with zero objects.

Test script.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
obs = scene.objects[:]
obs.sort(key=lambda o: o.name)

def move(name, obs):
    # unlink from old collections
    for o in obs:
        for c in o.users_collection:
            c.objects.unlink(o)
    # make a new collection and link to it
    coll = bpy.data.collections.get(name)
    if not coll:
        coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
        scene.collection.children.link(coll)
    for o in obs:
        coll.objects.link(o)
    

while obs:
    name = obs[0].name.split(".")[0] 
    x = [o for o in obs if o.name.startswith(name)]
    move(name, x)
    obs = obs[len(x):]
    
# remove any now empty collections

empty_colls = [c for c in bpy.data.collections if not len(c.all_objects)]

while empty_colls:
    bpy.data.collections.remove(empty_colls.pop())
```