# How to rename objects based on LODs in python script?

Tags: python, objects, collections

I want to rename objects and their meshes by their triangle counts in a particular collection. The script should identify similar objects and put them in a collection then rename them based on their triangle counts in a format below:

Format:

- LOD0: Cube
- LOD1: Cube_LOD1
- LOD2: Cube_LOD2
- LOD3: Cube_LOD3
- LOD4: Cube_LOD4

  and so on...

**LOD0 should not have a suffix.**

[image]

---

From:

[image]

TO:

[image]

---

Comment: What do you mean with "similar objects" ?
Do you mean the name of the objects?

Comment: Yes the name of the objects

Comment: If there is a way to count triangles of meshes in the bpy, this should be very easy. Will see about it…

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard you can count faces easily (bmesh instances have a `faces` property, which you can pass to `len()`. However, if not all faces are triangles, you either need to triangulate first, or for higher performance, count vertices of each face and determine the number of triangles that face would produce. I found this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102597/finding-vertices-edges-faces-and-tris-using-python and the formula there is: `num_tris = sum(len(f.verts) - 2 for f in bm.faces)` or `num_tris = len(bm.calc_loop_triangles())`

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Okay, thanks! Now I just need to look up how to manage collections (will do this one unless you’re really interested in doing it tonight)…

Comment: could edit  tri-count into prior answer. to rename obs to "LOD's".   (_No getting around suffix if two (eg "Cube") objects have same tri count_)    Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/221829/15543  @ZargulTheWizard IMO would be a good exercise for OP to have a go at.

Comment: @batFINGER IDK what IMO or OP is in this context.

Comment: IDK what IDK is?

Comment: IMO - In My Opinion, OP - Original Poster (question asker), IDK - I Don't Know. UW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this script as a solution.

It automatically finds similar objects, sorts them by triangles, add them to collection and rename the object and the mesh.

Edit: doesn't make new set of collection when press twice

```
import bpy

def get_object_with_mesh():
    l = []
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.type == "MESH":
            l.append(obj)
    return l

def get_collection(name):
    collection = bpy.data.collections.get(name, None)
    if collection is None:
        coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(coll)
        return coll
    return collection

def get_basename(name):
    split = name.split(".")
    if split[-1].isnumeric():
        return get_basename(".".join(split[:-1]))
    else:
        split = name.split("_LOD")
        if split[-1].isnumeric():
            return get_basename("_LOD".join(split[:-1]))
        else:
            return "_LOD".join(split)

def get_similars(objects):
    object_dict = {}
    for obj in objects:
        name = get_basename(obj.name)
        object_dict.setdefault(name, [])
        object_dict[name].append(obj)
    return object_dict

def change_link_collection(collection, objects):
    # unlinkt
    for obj in objects:
        if obj in bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.values():
            bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.unlink(obj)
    # link
        if obj not in collection.objects.values():
            collection.objects.link(obj)

def count_triangles(object):
    object.data.calc_loop_triangles()
    return len(object.data.loop_triangles)

def rename_objects_by_triangles(objects, name, reverse):
    sorted_objects = sorted(objects, key= count_triangles, reverse= reverse)
    sorted_objects[0].name = name
    sorted_objects[0].data.name = name
    for i, obj in enumerate(sorted_objects[1:], 1):
        new_name = name + "_LOD" + str(i)
        obj.name = new_name
        obj.data.name = new_name
    return sorted_objects

def parent_objects(objects):
    for object in objects[1:]:
        object.parent = objects[0]
        object.matrix_parent_inverse = parent.matrix_world.inverted()

def append_to_collection(objects, name):
    if objects[0].parent is None:
        change_link_collection(self.get_collection("Meshes"), [objects[0]])
    parent_collection = get_collection("LODs")
    if len(objects) > 1 or objects[0].parent is not None:
        child_collection = get_collection("LOD_" + name)
        if child_collection in bpy.context.scene.collection.children.values():
            bpy.context.scene.collection.children.unlink(child_collection)
        if not (child_collection in parent_collection.children.values()):
            parent_collection.children.link(child_collection)
        if objects[0].parent is None:
            change_link_collection(child_collection, objects[1:])
        else:
            change_link_collection(child_collection, objects)
    

def main():
    object_dict = get_similars(get_object_with_mesh())
    for name in object_dict:
        # change the boolean value of the function "rename_objects_by_triangles" to sort:
        # from low to high triangles -> False                  |
        # from high to low triangles -> True                   V
        objects = rename_objects_by_triangles(object_dict[name], name, False)
        append_to_collection(objects, name)
        parent_objects(objects)
main()
```

To convert this script to an Operator:

I added an EnumProperty to decide with a dropdown to sort from 'High to Low' or from 'Low to High'

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import EnumProperty

class OBJECT_OT_collect_similars(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.collect_similars'
    bl_label = 'Collect Similar Object'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}
    
    sort : EnumProperty(name= 'sort', items= [('LTH','Low To High', ''),('HTL','High To Low','')])
    
    def execute(self, context):
        object_dict = self.get_similars(self.get_object_with_mesh())
        for name in object_dict:                       
            objects = self.rename_objects_by_triangles(object_dict[name], name, self.sort == 'HTL')
            self.parent_objects(objects)
            self.append_to_collection(objects, name)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def get_object_with_mesh(self):
        l = []
        for obj in bpy.data.objects:
            if obj.type == "MESH":
                l.append(obj)
        return l

    def get_collection(self, name):
        collection = bpy.data.collections.get(name, None)
        if collection is None:
            coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
            bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(coll)
            return coll
        return collection

    def get_basename(self, name):
        split = name.split(".")
        if split[-1].isnumeric():
            return self.get_basename(".".join(split[:-1]))
        else:
            split = name.split("_LOD")
            if split[-1].isnumeric():
                return self.get_basename("_LOD".join(split[:-1]))
            else:
                return "_LOD".join(split)

    def get_similars(self, objects):
        object_dict = {}
        for obj in objects:
            name = self.get_basename(obj.name)
            object_dict.setdefault(name, [])
            object_dict[name].append(obj)
        return object_dict

    def change_link_collection(self, collection, objects):
        # unlinkt
        for obj in objects:
            if obj in bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.values():
                bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.unlink(obj)
        # link
            if obj not in collection.objects.values():
                collection.objects.link(obj)

    def count_triangles(self, object):
        object.data.calc_loop_triangles()
        return len(object.data.loop_triangles)

    def rename_objects_by_triangles(self, objects, name, reverse):
        sorted_objects = sorted(objects, key= self.count_triangles, reverse= reverse)
        sorted_objects[0].name = name
        sorted_objects[0].data.name = name
        for i, obj in enumerate(sorted_objects[1:], 1):
            new_name = name + "_LOD" + str(i)
            obj.name = new_name
            obj.data.name = new_name
        return sorted_objects

    def parent_objects(self, objects):
        parent = objects[0]
        for object in objects[1:]:
            object.parent = parent
            object.matrix_parent_inverse = parent.matrix_world.inverted()
            

    def append_to_collection(self, objects, name):
        if objects[0].parent is None:
            self.change_link_collection(self.get_collection("Meshes"), [objects[0]])
        parent_collection = self.get_collection("LODs")
        if len(objects) > 1 or objects[0].parent is not None:
            child_collection = self.get_collection("LOD_" + name)
            if child_collection in bpy.context.scene.collection.children.values():
                bpy.context.scene.collection.children.unlink(child_collection)
            if not (child_collection in parent_collection.children.values()):
                parent_collection.children.link(child_collection)
            if objects[0].parent is None:
                self.change_link_collection(child_collection, objects[1:])
            else:
                self.change_link_collection(child_collection, objects)
            
bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_collect_similars)
```

Comment: It makes another set of collections when I press twice

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.

How to implement an Operator: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html

Comment: Not working with objects name Cube.001_LOD1, Cube.001_LOD2, Cube.001_LOD3, Cube.001_LOD4, etc :(

Comment: What do you want as a result?
Example: 'Cube.001' as base name or 'Cube' as base name

Comment: Cube as a base name and parent of all the LODs eg: LOD1, LOD2, etc

Comment: Ok I edited the script the way you want it. It will now remove all "_LOD" and ".001" etc. to get the base name

Comment: Can you parent all the LODs to Cube and set the material of parent to them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124249/discussion-between-rivin-and-karan-prakash).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
import bpy
name = 'Cube'  # case sensitive
collection_name = f'{name}.collection'
i = 0
obj = bpy.data.objects.get(name)
group = []
while obj: 
    # this loop assumes you don't have a missing object
    # (e.g. Cube, Cube.001, Cube.003 will not reach to the Cube.003)
    group.append(obj)
    i += 1
    obj = bpy.data.objects.get(f'{name}.{i:03d}')

'''lines 4-12 could be replaced with a single line below, but the line below
will match objects with names 'Cube.000', 'Cubes', 'Cube_copy' etc. as well
as it will go through all objects on the scene, which (rarely) could  be slow'''
# group = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.name.startswith(name)]

target_collection = bpy.data.collections.get(collection_name)
if not target_collection:
    target_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(target_collection)

def sort_key(obj):
    obj.data.calc_loop_triangles()
    return len(obj.data.loop_triangles)

result = list(enumerate(sorted(group, key=sort_key), start=1))
    
for i, obj in result:
    obj.name = name + (f'_LOD{i}' if i<len(result) else '') 
    for collection in obj.users_collection:
        collection.objects.unlink(obj)
    target_collection.objects.link(obj)
```

[image]

[How to put similar named objects into collection in python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/221816/60486)

[Finding Vertices, Edges, Faces, and Tris using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/102597/60486)