# What is the coding alternative for double edge loop select?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

Suppose I want to select the entire mesh boundary. Alt + RMB on a boundary edge would select one edge loop (left image), while Alt + double RMB yields the desired result (right image).

[image: edge loop select]

How would I achieve this result by scripting? Assume the user first selects one boundary edge manually. I reckon it is buried somewhere in this function:

`bpy.ops.mesh.loop_select(extend=False, deselect=False, toggle=False, ring=False)`

But I can't quite understand how to use this function. Examples on how to do this would be very much welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bmesh script.**

With a single boundary edge selected in edit mode, the LHS of question images can be achieved calling `bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select()` directly from the python console.

```
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select(
loop_multi_select()
bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select(ring=False)
Select a loop of connected edges by connection type
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select()
{'FINISHED'}
```

[image]

The `mesh.loop_select` operator is a different kettle of fish and requires context override if called from outside the 3D view.

*This is a matter of giving the context override dictionary a 3d view "area", "space_data" and "region"*

However even then, with all combos of options it still did not perform as did the alt double click on my test mesh.

**Use `bmesh`.**

IMO edit mode mesh operators can become mind-numbingly annoying to code when they cannot be "made to perform" as desired

Touched on some  other reasons to avoid operators [Element indices messed up after switching from Edit to Object Mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172593/element-indices-messed-up-after-switching-from-edit-to-object-mode)

Can instead create our own methods

The boundary select function below takes an edge, tags it, looks at all untagged boundary edges linked to its two end verts, tags them and so on until it can go no further, then returns the edges.

Test script, run in edit mode with a single boundary edge selected.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from collections import defaultdict

context = bpy.context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

edge = bm.select_history.active

assert isinstance(edge, bmesh.types.BMEdge), "Select an Edge"

def boundary_select(edge):
    tag = defaultdict(bool)
    tag[edge] = True
    grow = True
    edges = [edge]
    while grow:
        more = [
        el for es in edges 
        for v in es.verts 
        for el in v.link_edges if not tag[el] and el.is_boundary
        ]
        edges.extend(more)
        for e in more:
            tag[e] = True
        grow = bool(more)
    return edges
        
for e in boundary_select(edge):
    e.select_set(True)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

[Persistence of element tag and select using bound bmesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199278/persistence-of-element-tag-and-select-using-bound-bmesh)

[How to detect disconnected parts within a selection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199005/how-to-detect-disconnected-parts-within-a-selection)

Comment: Alright this has answered my question. Hoped it would be easier to use the bpy operator instead of recreating the method. Does context override have disadvantages? When would you use override instead of creating your own method?

Comment: Chances are can use the operator, couldn't crack it, but am slowly learning not to bother if can do it with bmesh. (in less time). Re overriding context, would make a good question (may be one IIRC) I am of the view that if you make a method like above,  it takes context out of equation. All that matters is a valid bmesh. (btw have another similar answer re this somewhere that orders edges --> slice n feed into bmesh grid fill for instance)  Possibly most important is what _you_ wish to achieve via scripting.  Covered some of this in prior answers to your questions.  Started coding blender

Comment: in 2.49, then 2.5 brought in `bpy` with no `bmesh`. Used to write all mesh manipulation either via ops or manipulating mesh data.  Had no idea how to use `bmesh` for a long while, after it arrived, and was all the rage. (similarly with  cycles and material nodes lol) . When it twigs, its nigh on impossible to look back . .. tho, to reiterate, depends on your use case.