# Blender closes when running script

Tags: scripting

I am running a script that applies a loose neuroevolutionary algorithm to wind turbine fans in blender.  Here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mhblXNEe3jelaexI_qPRFmD-nOIVNwGw).  Whenever I run the script blender runs it at roughly 50-60% of my CPU computing power, then jumps to 100%, and then closes.  The same thing happens for my memory.  I am running blender 2.8 on windows 10.  What is going on?

```py
def print_array(a, size=1):  # prints cubes based on the array
    #create an array with all of the units filled in
    #not that relevant but is useful for under standing
    count = a.shape[0] * a.shape[1] * a.shape[2]
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=size, location=(0, 0, 0))
    cube = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
    #0:x-axis 1:y-Axis 2:z-Axis
    for i in range(3):
        mod = cube.modifiers.new('Array', 'ARRAY')
        mod.relative_offset_displace[0] = 0
        mod.relative_offset_displace[i] = 1.01
        mod.count = a.shape[i]
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Array')
    bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
    for i in bpy.data.objects:
        bpy.data.objects[i.name].select_set(False)
    #destroy the "zeros" in the array
    indexes = np.where(a == 0)
    print('found indexes')
    #create a list of the zeros
    zeros = []
    for i in range(indexes[0].shape[0]):
        zeros.append([indexes[0][i], indexes[1][i], indexes[2][i]])
    #find the number of the index
    objs = bpy.data.objects
    for i in zeros:
        print(i)
        coor = i[2] * a.shape[0] * a.shape[1] + i[1] * a.shape[0] + i[0]
        print('coor: ', coor)
        if coor == 0:
            string = "Cube"    
        elif len(str(coor)) == 1:
            string = "Cube.00" + str(coor)
        elif len(str(coor)) == 2:
            string = "Cube.0" + str(coor)
        else:
            string = "Cube." + str(coor)
        bpy.data.objects[string].select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
        count -= 1
    return count

def update_array(array, values_changed):
    shape = array.shape
    values = [0, 1]
    coordinates = []
    for i in range(values_changed):
        coordinates.append([random.randint(0, array.shape[0] - 1), random.randint(0, array.shape[1] - 1), random.randint(0, array.shape[2] - 1)])
    coor = []
    for x in coordinates:
        if x not in coor:
            coor.append(x)
    for i in coor:
        array[i[0], i[1], i[2]] = random.choice(values)
        print(i[0], i[1], i[2])
    return array

def train_on_generation(generation, folder_name, creatures, values_changed):
    losses = []
    os.chdir(folder_name)
    if not os.path.exists('Generation %s' % generation):
        os.mkdir('Generation %s' % generation)
    os.chdir(folder_name + ('Generation %s' % generation))
    if generation == 0:
        for i in range(creatures):
            np.save('creature %s' % i, update_array(np.ones((25, 250, 5)), values_changed))
        creature_num = 0
        for i in os.listdir(folder_name + ('Generation %s' % generation)):
            print_array(np.load(i))
            losses.append(0)  # is an actual loss function in original code
            for i in bpy.data.objects:
                if not i.name[0] == 'F':
                    bpy.data.objects[i.name].select_set(True)
                    bpy.ops.object.delete()  # deletes everything but the wind force fields
        #get the highest loss and the creature_num
        highest_loss = 0
        for i in losses:
            if i > highest_loss:
                highest_loss = i
        index = losses.index(highest_loss)
        losses = []
        #set the best array as creature_best
        best = np.load(folder_name + 'Generation 0/' + ('creature %s' % index))
        np.save(folder_name + 'Generation 0/creature_best', best)
    else:  # same thing as the top
        for i in range(creatures):
            np.save('creature %s' % creature_num, update_array(np.load(folder_name + ('Generation %s/' % (generation - 1)) + 'creature_best')), values_changed)
        creature_num = 0
        for i in os.listdir(folder_name + ('Generation %s' % generation)):
            print_array(np.load(i))
            losses.append(0)
            for i in bpy.data.objects:
                if not i.name[0] == 'F':
                    bpy.data.objects[i.name].select_set(True)
                    bpy.ops.object.delete()  # deletes everything but the wind force fields
        highest_loss = 0
        for i in losses:
            if i > highest_loss:
                highest_loss = i
        index = losses.index(highest_loss)
        #set the best array as creature_best
        best = np.load(folder_name + ('Generation %s/' % generation) + ('creature %s' % index))
        np.save(folder_name + ('Generation %s/creature_best' % generation), best)
        losses = []

filepath = '' # the folder to store the creatures

for i in range(10):
    train_on_generation(i, filepath, 10, 10)
```

Sorry I couldn't shorten it more than that :/.

Comment: Hi. Please include any *relevant* parts of the script (or a simplified version which still shows the issue) in the question body itself. Thanks.

Comment: Does it crash on smaller numbers? No errors in console? could be a removed reference error.  Another possibility  see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators  How many operator calls are we looking at here? Can certainly replace delete operator above.  Also recommend using `objs = scene.objects`  when working with context.  Selecting objects in `bpy.data.objects` collection has no relevance if not linked or to be linked to scene.

Comment: @batFINGER What I am confused about is that it works for the first 9 numpy arrays and then crashes which says to me that its not about the size of the array but something else.

Comment: The strange thing is that it does work for a smaller numpy array.   Doesn't python get rid of variables that it no longer uses so the actual size of the arrays shouldn't matter, at least in the code executing?