# Blender python trying to scale the uv

Tags: python

I am trying to enlarge the uv map  using python scripting so more square in my texture. Not sure what is wrong.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
XYZcoord = (0, 0 ,0)
ob = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=XYZcoord)
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=( 20, 20, 20))
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=10)
bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
material_image = bpy.data.materials.new(name= "Basic_Texture")
material_image.use_nodes = True
principled_node = material_image.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')
principled_node.inputs[7].default_value = 0.08
texImage = material_image.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.location = (-300, 400)
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load("H:\\blender__texture_maps_ao_normal_height_etc\\Wooden_planks_04_2K_Base_Color.png")
material_image.node_tree.links.new(principled_node.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])
texImage_rough = material_image.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage_rough.location = (-300, 0)
texImage_rough.image = bpy.data.images.load("H:\\blender__texture_maps_ao_normal_height_etc\\Wooden_planks_04_2K_Roughness.png")
texImage_rough.image.colorspace_settings.name = 'Non-Color'
material_image.node_tree.links.new(principled_node.inputs['Roughness'], texImage_rough.outputs['Color'])
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
bpy.context.object.active_material = material_image


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.uv.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='EDGE')
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'UV'
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(2, 2, 2), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
print(bpy.context.active_object)
```

Comment: could you add an image of result and expected result?  UV maps 0 to 1 in U to image width and v to height.

Answer (score 2):

**Reducing Operators**

Currently the question code has 14 operators, most of which can be easily replaced with API methods.

[Python performance with Blender operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators)

**Creating the grid.**

Replace the add plane, subdivide scale with a single create primitive grid operator.  *Could also replace this operator*

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(
        location=(0, 0, 0),
        x_subdivisions=12,
        y_subdivisions=12,
        size=2,
        )
grid = bpy.context.object
grid.scale *= 20
me = grid.data
```

or to apply scale, and have unit scale grid

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(
        x_subdivisions=12,
        y_subdivisions=12,
        size=40,
        )
grid = bpy.context.object
me = grid.data
```

The UV is generated with the primitive, so no need to UV project in this instance.

[image]
*The operator generated UV*

**Scaling UV with numpy.**

*In regard to scaling the UV, if we have a mesh with a UV can use something like below, to scale by `(scale_u, scale_v)` about some UV center point.  This is the same result as [@IceSandwich](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210097/15543) without iterating over the UVs via loops*

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Matrix
center = (0.5, 0.5)
scale = (2, 2)

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
uv_layer = me.uv_layers.active

uvs = np.empty((2 * len(uv_layer.data), 1), "f")
uv_layer.data.foreach_get('uv', uvs)
S = Matrix.Diagonal(scale)
scaled_uvs = np.dot(uvs.reshape((-1, 2)) - center, S) + center
uv_layer.data.foreach_set('uv', scaled_uvs.ravel())
```

will elaborate more if need be after question edit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u forget to add 'R' before the file path?

bpy.data.images.load(**R**"H:\blender__texture_maps_ao_normal_height_etc\Wooden_planks_04_2K_Base_Color.png")

It should raise an error in python but my blender doesn't show any error message. Everything works fine in my blender.

**Edit**: You can use the following code to scale your uv instead of using `bpy.ops.transform.resize`
See more information [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.Mesh.html)

```
me = bpy.context.object.data
uv_layer = me.uv_layers.active.data

scale_factor = 2
for poly in me.polygons:
    for loop_index in range(poly.loop_start, poly.loop_start + poly.loop_total):
        # rearrange uv coordinate from 0~1 to -1~1 and scale it.
        uv_layer[loop_index].uv.x = (uv_layer[loop_index].uv.x - 0.5) * 2 * scale_factor / 2 + 0.5
        uv_layer[loop_index].uv.y = (uv_layer[loop_index].uv.y - 0.5) * 2 * scale_factor / 2 + 0.5
```

Comment: the issue it not the image... it scaling the mesh.