# How to apply alpha clip to model shape?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I'm trying to use game models for 3d printing. I have imported the character's hair model shape. I've applied 3 modifiers to it:

- A Solidify modifier with 0.005 m
- A Subdivision modifier with 5 Levels
- and a Displace modifier with the alpha texture with UV coordinates,
  0.002 strength.

but when I apply it, it doesn't seem to remove all the material. Anything I can try to solve this and remove the excess flap material without manually knifing them out manually?

[image: trying to remove the excess material on the flap]

[image: the texture for the displacement]

Comment: This might not be helpful but another entirely different approach might be [auto-tracing the alpha map in inkscape](https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) and importing the resulting svg into blender which would at least give you clean edges. If you can unwrap the hair mesh [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/231662/599), then maybe you can boolean intersect the hair mesh with the traced svg and then re-wrap it back to the original shape? I'm honestly not sure if that's really feasible or not, just an idea