# Blender taking too long to create an object with python code

Tags: python

I've been modeling neurons in Blender using python code. This is the best way I've found to import cylinders (each representing a slice of a neuron) of a certain radius, depth, and position. Then I name the cylinder and assign it a material.

```
import bpy 
import csv 
with open ('C:/Users/scrill2015/Desktop/Modeling/Neuron 57-2 EM Post Analysis wo Labels.csv') as f:    
    readout=list(csv.reader(f))
    #print(readout) 
for a in readout: 
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=32, radius=float(a[3]), depth=float(a[5]), enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 1000), scale=(1, 1, 1)) 
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, orient_axis='X', orient_type='VIEW', orient_matrix=((0.999984, -0.00558533, 2.27243e-07), (0.00311015, 0.556867, 0.830596), (-0.00463928, -0.830583, 0.556876)), orient_matrix_type='VIEW', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.context.object.location[1] = float(a[6])
    bpy.context.active_object.name = (a[0])
    mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Silhouette")
    bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(mat)
```

The cylinders are being produced at a rate of 1-2 seconds per cylinder, meaning a neuron made up of 1900 cylinders takes over an hour. My boss says that it should occur on a magnitude of microseconds. Is there anything I can do my code to optimize the time it takes to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to `bpy.ops` are slow, and get slower the more objects there are in the scene. See [Python performance with Blender operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators/7360#7360). It's faster to use the lower level APIs than the operators.

In this case for example, you can create one cylinder as a "template", then copy and scale it to produce a cylinder with a different radius/depth. This should be a lot faster.

```
import time
import math
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

# Create a cylinder to use as a "template"
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
    vertices=32,
    radius=1,
    depth=1,
    enter_editmode=False,
)
cyl = bpy.context.object.data
cyl.name = 'tmp'
bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.context.object, do_unlink=True)

# Fetch material to use
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Silhouette")

for ai, a in enumerate(readout):
    start_t = time.time()
    
    # Copy the template cylinder and scale it to the right radius/depth.
    mesh = cyl.copy()
    mesh.name = a[0]
    radius = float(a[3])
    depth = float(a[5])
    mesh.transform(Matrix.Diagonal([radius, radius, depth, 1]))

    mesh.materials.append(mat)

    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(a[0], mesh)
    ob.location = (0, float(a[6]), 1000)
    ob.rotation_euler[0] = -math.pi / 2

    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)

    print("%d : took %.4f" % (ai, time.time() - start_t))

# Done with the template cylinder so remove it
bpy.data.meshes.remove(cyl)
```

Not sure this exactly matches your code since its hard to test without your file, but it should be close enough for you to get the idea.

Comment: AMAZING! It worked in seconds. Thank you so much!