# NoneType has no attribute "modifier"

Tags: scripting

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects[f"{x.name}"]
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type = "DECIMATE")
                
bpy.context.object.modifier["Decimate"].ratio = Decimate_Ratio
```

`Decimate_Ratio` is just a math equation

I've tested the code alone without putting it in a function, but now I'm required to apply it to an addon and put it in a function and all the sudden the error appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the 's' that is missing in your code, you should avoid using `bpy.ops` for that.

Use for example something like this instead:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects['Cube']

decimate = obj.new(name='Decimate', type='DECIMATE')

decimate.ratio = 0.5
```

The reasons are: [`bpy.ops` is slower (it will cause GUI updates, etc.)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators) and most importantly you can't have a guaranty to access the modifier by its name like `bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"]` as Blender will name it differently in case of name conflicts (`Decimate`, `Decimate.001`, `Decimate.002`, ...). [`ObjectModifiers.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new) on the other hand, adds new modifier and returns a reference to the newly added modifier:

```
>>> C.object.modifiers.new('Decimate', 'DECIMATE')
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers["Decimate"]

>>> C.object.modifiers.new('Decimate', 'DECIMATE')
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers["Decimate.001"]

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `object.modifiers[]` with `s` in third line:

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].ratio = Decimate_Ratio
```