Is it possible to use low level python API to apply modifiers without slowing a loop?
I have a script adding several thousand objects into a blender scene.
After reading this post here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7360/124395
I have rewritten my code, such that it doesn't use any bpy.ops functions. This seems to work well, however I also add a geometry nodes modifier to each of the created objects. I would like to apply them immediately without slowing down my generation loop. Is there a way to do so on a lower level?
Here is some minimal code example:
import random
from math import pi
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Euler


bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
base_cube = bpy.context.active_object
base_cube.select_set(False)
for i in range(5):

    location = Vector(
        (
            random.uniform(-2.0, 2.0),
            random.uniform(-2.0, 2.0),
            random.uniform(15.0, 25.0),
        )
    )
    size = random.uniform(0.01, 0.1)

    rotation = Vector(
        (
            random.uniform(0.0, 2 * pi),
            random.uniform(0.0, 2 * pi),
            random.uniform(0.0, 2 * pi),
        )
    )


    name = f"rock_{i}"
    cube = bpy.context.object.copy()
    cube.name = name
    cube.data = base_object.data.copy()

    t = Matrix.Translation(location)
    r = Euler(rotation, "XYZ").to_matrix().to_4x4()
    s = Matrix.Diagonal(Vector((size, size, size))).to_4x4()

    tr = r @ s
    cube.data.transform(tr)
    cube.matrix_basis = t

    rock_modifier = cube.modifiers.new("RockGenerator", "NODES")
    rock_generator_geometry_node = bpy.data.node_groups["RockGenerator"]
    rock_modifier.node_group = rock_generator_geometry_node

    # change some of the default input values of the geo-node here
    bpy.data.collections["Rocks"].objects.link(cube)

    print(f"Generated {name}")

base_cube.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.delete()
bpy.context.view_layer.update()

I did some timings with the above code, while it already is much faster than my initial code using bpy.ops within the loop, it still gets slower and slower the higher the iterations get. Haven't yet found out the reason for this. In any case I still would like to apply the geo-node modifier as well without slowing down the iterations too much.

Create a minimal example of your problem, so we can see for example how you apply your geonodes modifier.

@MarkusvonBroady sure, I will add some example code as soon as I'm back in office.

@MarkusvonBroady sorry it took a while, but I have now added some additional example code.

This is not a correct example, I fixed 5 errors (imports, undefined variables) before I gave up.

Ahhrg, sorry copied together hastily from a bigger project. Fixed the code, hope I did not overlook something.

In any case, I am really just looking for a possible low-level API alternative to the bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply() function. So far I was not able to find anything in the docs or forums.

I think you want obj.to_mesh() see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh

note you can't directly assign this evaluated data to an actual blender mesh object

@Gorgious yes it seems like it.  I think I either have to leave the geo-node unassigned, or do it manually in the UI after the script has run. At the moment I have to do some additional performance tests, simply assigning the genonode with given parameters is very fast, even for 10000 objects, but as soon as I change some of the properties, performance will decrease a lot. I guess however this seems solvable :)

Note you can also use bpy.ops.object.modifier_copy_to_selected with an override at the end of the loop. Assign the modifier to a single object, then run the operator on all rock objects. I'm not sure about the performance though, and I would assume changing individual parameters afterwards will trigger a view layer update which will kill performance

@Gorgious actually, from what I can see atm (I am currently testing around and timing the generation script) is that adding the modifier is not the problem, but changing the default value (which seems the wrong way to do it anyway. My current approach is to modify not the default value of the geo-node, but of the objects modifier input via rock_modifier['Socket_10'] = some_value. If this works fast, I will report it as answer here.

As you already mentioned, I need individual parameters for each object, so after bpy.ops.object.modifier_copy_to_selected I would have to iterate through all the objects again anyway.

I think I have finally found a good solution, thanks @Gorgious for some inputs tipping me in the right direction.
I'll just leave a complete script here, which shows applying some geometry nodes parameters and a few other things as well. Important part is to add the attributes names to the geometry nodes in order to access them from the socket dictionaries:
import random
from math import pi
from time import time
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple

import bpy
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Euler, Matrix, Vector
from PIL import Image


def generate_modifer_attribute_map(modifier: bpy.types.NodesModifier) -> Dict[str, str]:

    socket_attribute_map = {}

    for k, v in modifier.items():
        if not k.endswith("_attribute_name"):
            continue

        socket_attribute_map[v] = k.replace("_attribute_name", "")

    return socket_attribute_map


def generate_stone_color_palette(save_to_file: bool = False) -> np.ndarray:
    greys = np.linspace((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0), 1024)
    browns = np.linspace((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0), 1024)
    blues = np.linspace((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0), 1024)

    cmbr = np.linspace(browns, greys, 1024)
    cmbl = np.linspace(greys, blues, 1024)
    cm = np.vstack((cmbr, cmbl))

    if save_to_file:
        Image.fromarray((cm * 255.0).astype(np.uint8)).save("cm.png")

    return cm


def sample_random_color(color_palette: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[List[float]]:
    w, h = color_palette.shape[:2]
    random_index_w = np.random.randint(0, w)
    random_index_h = np.random.randint(0, h)

    c1 = color_palette[random_index_w, random_index_h].tolist()
    c2 = [c * 0.5 for c in c1]
    c2[3] = 1.0

    return (c1, c2)


def add_rock(
    name: str,
    base_object: bpy.types.Object,
    attribute_socket_map: Dict[str, str],
    location: Vector,
    color_1: List[float],
    color_2: List[float],
    size: float = 1.0,
    rotation: Vector = Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
) -> None:
    cube = bpy.context.object.copy()
    cube.name = name
    cube.data = base_object.data.copy()

    t = Matrix.Translation(location)
    r = Euler(rotation, "XYZ").to_matrix().to_4x4()
    s = Matrix.Diagonal(Vector((size, size, size))).to_4x4()

    tr = r @ s
    cube.data.transform(tr)
    cube.matrix_basis = t

    rock_modifier = cube.modifiers["RockGenerator"]

    rock_modifier[attribute_socket_map["Proportions"]] = Vector(
        (
            random.uniform(0.5, 2.0),
            random.uniform(0.5, 2.0),
            random.uniform(0.5, 2.0),
        )
    )
    rock_modifier[attribute_socket_map["Shape Randomizer"]] = random.uniform(
        -9999999999.0, 9999999999.0
    )
    rock_modifier[attribute_socket_map["Edge Amount"]] = random.uniform(0.0, 2.0)
    rock_modifier[attribute_socket_map["Smoothness"]] = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    rock_modifier[attribute_socket_map["Color 1"]] = Vector(color_1)
    rock_modifier[attribute_socket_map["Color 2"]] = Vector(color_2)

    bpy.data.collections["Rocks"].objects.link(cube)


def main():

    random.seed()
    cm = generate_stone_color_palette()

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    base_cube = bpy.context.active_object
    base_cube.select_set(False)

    rock_generator_geometry_node = bpy.data.node_groups["RockGenerator"]
    rock_modifier = base_cube.modifiers.new("RockGenerator", "NODES")
    rock_modifier.node_group = rock_generator_geometry_node

    as_map = generate_modifer_attribute_map(rock_modifier)

    start = time()
    for i in range(5000):

        location = Vector(
            (
                random.uniform(-2.0, 2.0),
                random.uniform(-2.0, 2.0),
                random.uniform(15.0, 25.0),
            )
        )
        size = random.uniform(0.01, 0.1)

        rotation = Vector(
            (
                random.uniform(0.0, 2 * pi),
                random.uniform(0.0, 2 * pi),
                random.uniform(0.0, 2 * pi),
            )
        )

        color_1, color_2 = sample_random_color(cm)

        name = f"rock_{i}"
        add_rock(
            name=name,
            base_object=base_cube,
            attribute_socket_map=as_map,
            location=location,
            size=size,
            rotation=rotation,
            color_1=color_1,
            color_2=color_2,
        )

    end = time()
    print(f"Time needed to gnerate: {end - start}")
    base_cube.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

With this, the loop to generate 5000 stones takes around 1.6 seconds on my notebook, which is a vast improvements to the several minutes it took when I still used bpy operators (Although I have to admit, that the view layer update still takes several seconds due to the high amount of objects.
Here is the result:

