# Add a simple vertex via python

Tags: python, vertices

How can I add a Vertex from a script?
I'd like to create a line from the extrusion of a vertex.
This is my script now:

```
import bpy

location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location    # Get Cursor location
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()                # Enter Edit Mode

# Here goes the script I'm looking for!

bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move()              # Extrude vertex
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass a list of vertex coordinates to [`Mesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=from_pydata#bpy.types.Mesh.from_pydata) However, you also have to create a *new mesh* as well as a *new object datablock* and link them together properly:

**Blender 2.8x**

```
import bpy

def point_cloud(ob_name, coords, edges=[], faces=[]):
    """Create point cloud object based on given coordinates and name.

    Keyword arguments:
    ob_name -- new object name
    coords -- float triplets eg: [(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0), (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)]
    """

    # Create new mesh and a new object
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(ob_name + "Mesh")
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(ob_name, me)

    # Make a mesh from a list of vertices/edges/faces
    me.from_pydata(coords, edges, faces)

    # Display name and update the mesh
    ob.show_name = True
    me.update()
    return ob

# Create the object
pc = point_cloud("point-cloud", [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)])

# Link object to the active collection
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(pc)

# Alternatively Link object to scene collection
#bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(pc)
```

**Blender 2.7x**

```
import bpy

def point_cloud(ob_name, coords, edges=[], faces=[]):
    """Create point cloud object based on given coordinates and name.

    Keyword arguments:
    ob_name -- new object name
    coords -- float triplets eg: [(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0), (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)]
    """

    # Create new mesh and a new object
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(ob_name + "Mesh")
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(ob_name, me)

    # Make a mesh from a list of vertices/edges/faces
    me.from_pydata(coords, edges, faces)

    # Display name and update the mesh
    ob.show_name = True
    me.update()
    return ob

# Create the object
pc = point_cloud("point-cloud", [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)])

# Link object to the scene
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(pc)
```