# Create vertices with python

Tags: python, mesh, objects, vertices, data-blocks

I'm new scripting Blender but I could write the following:

```
import bpy
obj_name = "maki"
mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new(obj_name + "_data")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new(obj_name, mesh_data)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
# Sample vertex data
verts = [(0.154, 0.5151, 2.213), (2.847, -3.15, 0.151), (1.247, -1.105, 0.965)]
mesh_data.from_pydata(verts, [], [])
```

Is this the right way to do that?

Comment: Looks good. You've got 2 options, [Bmesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/414/31447) (more flexible) and [without Bmesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23086/31447) (easier).