# Trying to draw a specific curve with Python

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves

I am an amateur and beginner using Blender 2.82a on my Windows PC (nothing fancy). I am trying to make a 3D animation of some pipes, but I am stuck at even the very beginning.

I am extremely bad at conceptualizing "free-drawing" art, but mathematically I know where to set the vertices and the connections to get the proper shape (figure below).

[image]
.
The problem is that I have looked at endless tutorials and read many articles as to how I can do this and I have not found a single article that addresses how to at the very least setup the vertex points individually. The closest I have to come to doing so is using the procedure outlined in [this web page](https://medium.com/@behreajj/scripting-curves-in-blender-with-python-c487097efd13). I would appreciate if somebody could direct me or show me how to create individual vertices and how to setup them one by one...think of the problem as:

> I give you a set of point $$S={\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2,\ldots \vec{x}_n}$$ points with a list that tells you how to connect the points with straight lines.

How can I achieve this using the Python console? Even just clicking on them and setting them using the input boxes of the GUI would work for me.

Comment: Have a look at _`Text Editor > Templates > Python > Addon Add Object`_ template in the text editor.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23086/add-a-simple-vertex-via-python