# How to fit a grid to a set of vertices

Tags: python, modifiers, vertices

I have a 10 x 10 Grid that I have deleted all faces and edges:
[image: Blender Grid]
I then used proportional editing to make it arched.

I am wondering, is there a way to take another grid (one that has more points, i.e. 100 x 100) and make it fit to this set of vertices?

I have tried the `shrinkwrap` modifier, but I couldn't get it to work on vertices. Any help would be appreciated (I am not afraid of using a python solution either, just figured there was an easy way I am missing).

Comment: Is there a reason for the faces+edges deletion? I think they could have helped you so much in this task (you can always delete them at the end of modeling).

Comment: This is a very simple example, where I created the vertices myself. Where I want to apply this, I am just given the vertices, and there are never any faces or edges. Trying to create the faces and edges by selecting all and hitting "f" doesn't do what is expected. Instead of recreating the grid, it creates a mess. I know that I could then just select the edge loops and do a grid fill, but once again, this is a simple example and in my real problem, that is not an option. So I just have vertices.

Comment: Might be interesting: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19655/creating-a-point-cloud-from-the-surfaces-of-a-model/19680#19680 ?

Comment: That is interesting, but I am afraid it doesn't help in this case