# How to find evenly spaced coordinates/point cloud of an object?

Tags: python, coordinates, point-clouds

I'd like to convert a mesh object into a point cloud. I started using the vertices:

```
coordinates = []
for x in range(len(obj.data.vertices)):
    v = obj.matrix_world * obj.data.vertices[x].co
    coordinates.append(v)
```

Plotting the coordinates I get a point cloud as expected:
[image: Chair Point Cloud]

However, depending on the mesh, there are huge irregular gaps between the points. Is there a way to "interpolate" between the coordinates to get a regular pointcloud?

I found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19655/creating-a-point-cloud-from-the-surfaces-of-a-model) proposal but couldn't make use of it.

Comment: Are you planning to use this data in Blender or another program?  Your answer may allow different answers to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I am planning to export the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Remesh Modifier. [Apply] the Remesh modifier with the button in the modifier to get a new mesh with vertices equally spaced as a simple description.

Remesh On Below.  View Eye Active.
[image]

Remesh Off Below.  View Eye Inactive.
[image]

You may also consider the Loop Cut Tool if you want some particular control of the division of loop cuts.

[image]

A Blender Particle System can emulate the point cloud.

[image]

Close up view of the particles emitted from vertices.

[image]

Comment: to have even space / grid like you may use *emit: faces* + *particles/face = 1* (onli for jitter variant..) or so

Comment: Thank you, the remesh method works fine! However, I am still facing one problem: If the mesh is not "one piece" it gets deformed very badly (I hope that description is clear)

Comment: Ahh, stupid, I didn't see the "Remove disconnected pieces" option. So thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to **set particles on the object and to use GRID instead of (default) random** in the settings
(Note that **also works on Volume**, if the case, to fill with points)

Use No for physics to get fixed particles.

---

To further get the coordinates of those particles use:

```
gridVectors = [p.location for p in bpy.data.objects['Cube'].particle_systems[0].particles]
```

that if u need to further use coords in script

---

Also note that the grid acts a bit weird sometimes, more like the remesh tools, so the particles may or may not be on the faces, but rather at a distance, not quite controllable.

In the pic, I added particles to these meshes with settings as shown.
[image]

Comment: You wrote [a variant]. A variant of what?

Comment: A variant of getting even points. By saying "a variant" I assume there are other ways. Also I'm not very pleased by the level of control over grid particles, or how they work sometimes.    Should I say "a solution" ?

Comment: Thank you, but I can't find this option in Blender 2.74. What is the Python API method for this action?

Comment: Sorry, I updated now to show I use particles. And what you see is particles settings.