# Aperture Diaphragm in Blender 2.8

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, instances

Blender Newbie here.

I looked for a way to model an aperture lens and found this question: [How do I rig each blade to fan out like an aperture lens?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38689/how-do-i-rig-each-blade-to-fan-out-like-an-aperture-lens)

The questions has been answered very well (Thanks Carlo) but when I try to redo this in Blender 2.8 I'm stuck at the following point (yes, right in the beginning).

I have created a triangle and a circle. The triangle is child of the circle. I activated Instancing on Verts because this is from what I understood the new "duplivert". 
But, there is not "rotation" setting in Instancing and I have no idea how to rotate the instanced triangles so that they are pointing to the center.

[image]

Or is there a better way to achieve this?

I tried the array modifier but this need the Pivot Point to be in the center (and I need it elsewhere for the copy rotation constraint afterwards)

I tried spinning but this does not work at all for flat objects like a plane.

I really tried to find a solution for a few hours now and you are my last hope. :)

Thanks in advance for any hint.

EDIT:

Once I try to use *Align to Vertex Normal* it's getting out of hands. :)

Is there a way to adjust the vertex normal or what am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108541/animate-a-spheres-system-as-a-camera-diaphragm/108546#108546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still there, just the name is changed :).
Now it's called  *Align to Vertex Normal* *✓*

[image]

When setting up the constraint, change *Mix* to *Add*.
Otherwise the triangles won't line up later.

[image]

You can add the constraint to other objects using *Object > Constraint > Copy Constraints*. Just make sure, the constraint isn't on the circle itself :).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This has a strange effect for me that you can see in the edited post. Unfortunately I have no clue how to adjust the Vertex normals. I already tried this but gave up when it ended like that...

Comment: Hello :). You can solve this by applying transforms on your triangle (*Object > Apply > All transforms*) and also moving the *origin point* to the shortest side (*Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor*).

Comment: Hi there, thanks again. That really worked. I had some problems shifting the Origin around and now it looks pretty good. But there is one more thing: When I Apply > Make Instances Real the Object Constraint (Copy Rotation) is lost. and only the original Triangle can be rotated. I also cannot see the original triangle in your screencapture, did you just hide it? How do I keep the constraints?

Comment: Thanks to you everything is working fine now! How can I buy you a beer here? ;)