# Animate an object that has a Circular Array

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature

I would like to animate articulated petals opening around a circle base, like a blooming flower would. Since the design will evolve and become more complex, I'd like to keep the Array modifier or at least reduce the number of steps in case I need to modify the mesh.

Here is the default position:
[image: petals]
I've been playing with empty and Armatures but beside applying the modifier and duplicating the armature around an empty, I can't figure out an efficient solution.

Here's the mess I get as long as the Array isn't applied
[image: fail]

Comment: hello maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Related: [Aperture Diaphragm in Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170861/78972)

Comment: Thanks for the replies,I uploaded the array blend file and will try with the "align to vertex normal" and constraints tomorrow!

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=J0DYabl1" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/J0DYabl1/)

Comment: @Jachym Michal so I tried with the constraints and instancing, but it seems the all the instances use the original object X axis value instead of their local values. I've tried "Copy>Constraint>Copy constraint to object" but unlike the person from that thread, it applies it to the vertex circle instead of each instances.